# pip install PyQt IOError

Tags: python, pyqt, pip, ioerror, setup.py

I'm trying to install PyQt package with pip, but I get this error:

```
~$ pip install PyQt

Downloading/unpacking PyQt  
Downloading PyQt-x11-gpl-4.8.3.tar.gz
(9.8Mb): 9.8Mb downloaded   Running
setup.py egg_info for package PyQt
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'/home/john/build/PyQt/setup.py'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in
<module>

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or
directory:
'/home/john/build/PyQt/setup.py

---------------------------------------- Command python setup.py egg_info
failed with error code 1 Storing
complete log in
/home/john/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: Someone added an issue here: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/579

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's because that file has a `configure.py` not a `setup.py`.  configure.py generate a make file that you use to build pyqt against the qt lib you choose by passing --qmake option to configure.py, it has different options too. I suggest filing a bug with the pip maintainer.

Comment: To clarify: you can still build this package by manually downloading it and following its install instructions.

Comment: @hector It should be with pip, the file actually comes from riverbank. They don't have *nix binaries, just windows. easy_install handles it fine ftr.

Comment: Nope easy_install doesn't know how to handle it as well

Answer (score 9):

If you're on Mac, you can use [homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install pyqt
```

Answer (score 5):

You can, alternatively, [install PyQt4](http://code.activestate.com/pypm/pyqt4/) using [ActivePython](http://www.activestate.com/activepython/downloads#content)'s binary package manager.

```
$ pypm install pyqt4
The following packages will be installed into "~/.local" (2.7):
 pyqt4-4.8.3.0
Hit: [pypm-free.activestate.com] pyqt4 4.8.3.0
Installing pyqt4-4.8.3.0
$
```

So long as you already have `PyPM`, no compilation required.

Answer (score 2):

Sharing my setup procedure:

1. create virtual environment on your project folder and activate:

   python3 -m venv venv
   source venv/bin/activate
2. use pip to install PyQt5 (Note: specify the version especially on Centos7)

   pip3 install pyqt5==5.14

Answer (score 1):

you can pip install the directory of the downloaded version of pyqt after you download it ..google for your desired version

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my raspberry-pi 3 model B (rasberry pi os)
and I resolved it using `apt-get`

Here:

`pip3 install --user pyqt5`

`sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5`

Optionally:

`sudo apt-get install pyqt5-dev-tools`

`sudo apt-get install qttools5-dev-tools`