# Installing Spynner on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, pyqt, spynner

I'm trying to use Python's `spynner` module in a Heroku app, but I'm having trouble getting it working on Heroku.  I obviously have it in my `requirements.txt` and that's fine, even installing `lxml` with no problem, but I run into a problem with PyQt4.  It's not listed in its dependencies, and if I manually put a statement in the `requirements.txt` like `pyqt>=0.0.0`, it does try to install it, but I always end up with the following error:

```
       Downloading/unpacking pyqt>=0.0.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 12))
         Storing download in cache at /app/tmp/repo.git/.cache/pip_downloads/htt
p%3A%2F%2Fwww.riverbankcomputing.com%2Fstatic%2FDownloads%2FPyQt4%2FPyQt-x11-gpl
-4.9.4.tar.gz
         Running setup.py egg_info for package pyqt
           Traceback (most recent call last):
             File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
           IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build_11i9jfrncqa
t2/.heroku/venv/build/pyqt/setup.py'
           Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
           Traceback (most recent call last):

         File "<string>", line 14, in <module>

       IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build_11i9jfrncqat2/.
heroku/venv/build/pyqt/setup.py'

       ----------------------------------------
       Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/build_1
1i9jfrncqat2/.heroku/venv/build/pyqt
       Storing complete log in /app/.pip/pip.log
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Python app
```

No matter what I do, even trying manual `heroku run easy_install xxx` with some PyQt4 distribution, it never works.  Does anyone have any advice on how to get spynner running?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it locally? I don't think this bug has anything to do with Heroku. As of this writing, you can't install pyqt from pip anywhere. See [pip install PyQt IOError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517924/pip-install-pyqt-ioerror)

Comment: That is correct, and that is exactly the issue, because as far as I know you'd need to use `pip` to install it on Heroku.