# Python matplotlib Cairo error

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, python-3.4

I'm using something simpler than the sample code on the [pyplot tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html) website:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5])
plt.show()
```

but when I run it, I get the error:

`TypeError: Couldn't find foreign struct converter for 'cairo.Context'`

I'm on Python 3.4.2, and have a fresh install of matplotlib, cairocfft>0.6, numpy>=1.6 from pip.

I tried uninstalling cairocfft and grabbing `python-cairo` from the Arch repositories, but now I have the error:

`NotImplementedError: Surface.create_for_data: Not Implemented yet.`

Is there a way to draw a basic line graph without installing many libraries? I'm not enthusiastic on [installing pyqt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517924/pip-install-pyqt-ioerror), as [this blogpost](http://blogs.bu.edu/mhirsch/2014/05/matplotlib-python3-fixing-pyplot-imshow/) recommends. [This github issue](https://github.com/jflesch/paperwork/issues/283) suggests installing gi-cairo, but gi-cairo is not on the [Arch repositories](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?sort=&q=cairo+gi&maintainer=&flagged=), nor could I find it on PyPI (my own search fail?)

I remember this being a breeze on Python2, but have migrated to Python3 now.

Comment: Work fine for me on Arch. I've got python 3.4.2 and python-cairo 1.10.0-4.

Comment: Do you have `python-gobject` installed?

Comment: @nwk yes, `python-gobject` is installed.

Comment: If you want a gui interface, then you need a gui framework.  Mpl supports qt, gtk, wx and tk (plus OSX, windows?, ipython notebooks/web browsers).  As for drawing, any reason you need to use cairo?  The Agg backends work fine if you want raster and the svg/ps/pdf backends should have most of the bases covered for vector graphics.

Comment: Hmm this is probably a bad question. I'm using cairo since it's the default. The pdf backend seems really nice and works so I'll just sidestep this problem for now.

Comment: I got the same error in Python 3.4.1, but changing backend from GTK3Agg to TkAgg now it works fine.

Comment: Found the way to do that at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17393928/cannot-import-matplotlib-pyplot-in-python-3

Comment: The best solution is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41279477/3029388) by @Dominykas.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is in case someone is having the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04, as I did using Python 3.4.3. By using bits and hints from JDong's answer, I've solved the problem as follows. (Basically change the MatPlotLib backend to `qt5agg`.)

1. Install `python3-pyqt5`.

   `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5`
2. Find out where the `matplotlibrc` file is so you can edit it. This can be done using the following in Python console.

   `import matplotlib
   matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()`
3. Edit the `matplotlibrc` file (you'll probably require `sudo`), find the line beginning with `backend :`, and change it to `backend : qt5agg`. If such a line doesn't exist, just create one.

The above steps have solved it for me on Ubuntu 14.04. I hope that helps.

Comment: Confirmed to work in Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 3.4 - FWIW the file appear to be installed in `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc` and that should be the same for everyone (although the method suggested by @Ray works just fine).

Answer (score 6):

This does seem to be a real issue; upon further playing I found an error message:

```
/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_gtk3agg.py:18:
UserWarning: The Gtk3Agg backend is known to not work on Python 3.x with pycairo.
Try installing cairocffi.
"The Gtk3Agg backend is known to not work on Python 3.x with pycairo."
```

Oddly however, I did install `cairocffi`. The best solution I found is to use a different backend, as tcaswell suggested in the comments. I found export to pdf very agreeable with just the line: `plt.savefig("Graph.pdf")`.

skytux mentions that changing the backend to Tk works. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21791045/2534876 shows how to do this.

Mar 2016 update: [plotly](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plotly) is a great alternative to matplotlib that I use now. It works with the browser to generate documents and I haven't had platform issues.

Answer (score 4):

Upon installation Matplotlib warned me to install cairocffi, because of incompatibilities in my system. After experiencing the `NotImplementedError` (plots not being drawn), installing Debian's `python3-cairocffi` package solved the problem.

Comment: This should be voted up. Much better solution than changing the backend to Qt.

Comment: Actually, this one is the best solution.

Answer (score 4):

Installing `python-gi-cairo` using `sudo apt-get install python-gi-cairo` solved my problem

Comment: In my case (Debian 9.2), the accepted answer didn't help but this one did!

Answer (score 3):

In the case of Python 2.7 it can be solved by installing the package `python-pyqt5` and using pyplot like this:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

If you have sudo acces you can also set `Qt5Agg` as your default backend, see [Matplotlib Backend](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) for other ways to set your backend.